# Security API auth and $ variables not equal

Tags: firebase

I tried the following security rule for my application but i ran into a problem. I have one user in my firebase and the unique id is 2.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've checked that when i do `".write": "$user == 2"`, i won't be able to write on firebase, but when i do `".write": "$user == '2'"`, i will be able to write on firebase.

On the other hand when i do `".write": "auth.id == 2"`, i will be able to write on firebase.

It seems that $user is being treated as a string whereas auth.id is being treated as a number. I've checked the documentation at https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/ but it proved to be unhelpful on this matter.

In a desperate attempt, i tried `".write": "$user == auth.id.toString()"` which of course gave me this error: "6:29:Type error: Function call on target that is not a function."

Can anyone provide me with some advice on this matter?

The only workaround i can think of is to also include "userId" as a child to $user, which would be read as a number value rather than a string.

Answer (score 2):

There are two non-obvious details that may be tripping you up.

**Security rules are always evaluated using `===`**

Your `==` is automatically converted to `===` by the security rules; to read more about it, check out the "[rules expressions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/index.html)" section of the document.

**Record IDs are converted to strings**

The user ID you inserted (2) is being converted to a string (I can't find the doc on that but remember reading it). In other words, the record ID is `"2"` and not `2` so your value in the auth data needs to match that.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Kato's right, though this is actually a bug on our end.  Your rules should work as-is.  As a temporary workaround you can change your rule to "$user == '' + auth.id" to convert auth.id to a string.  But this shouldn't be necessary long-term.

Comment: As @MichaelLehenbauer mentioned, this was a bug on our end. This should now be fixed (with auth.id properly treated as a string), but please reach out if you encounter any further problems.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I've just encountered this again with a hacker's plan, wasted half an hour debugging it. Workaround is good but am I doing something wrong? or is it not fixed yet.

Comment: @Joe If you're using Firebase Login (e.g. with our facebook, twitter, or email/password provider), then auth.id should be a string and so you can compare to any $-variable without issue.  If you're doing your own auth and auth.id is a number, then you'll still have to do the string conversion as described here by Kato.  Sorry!

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, I am in the latter group, using custom jwt for an existing system. I'm now passing in the id as a string so I don't have to do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround (mentioned in the comment of another answer) is required to get this to work for me in the Firebase Simulator:

`$user == '' + auth.id`